# Why doesn't a browser run a <script> in an HTML fragment retrieved via fetch API?

Tags: javascript

I was experimenting with getting a fragment of HTML using the fetch API, and then adding it to an HTML page. While this works fine for HTML content, I noticed that if I put a `<script>` tag in the fragment, the tag isn't stripped out, but it also isn't executed.

Below is an example. I would expect the `alert` to fire, but it doesn't, even though the script tag appears on the page.

My questions are (1) why does the `<script>` not get evaluated, and (2) is there a way to make it evaluate?

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### fragment.html

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>It works</p>
<script>
  alert('hello') // doesn't work, but script still appears on page
</script>
```

### main.js

```
fetch('fragment.html').then((res)=>{
  return res.text()
}).then((data)=>{
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.innerHTML = data
  document.body.appendChild(div)
})
```

Comment: Because script is only executed when loading the page.

Comment: you can use `$(elm).html(str)` instead of `elm.innerHTML=str;` to run such content.

Answer (score 4):

Because that's what the [HTML spec dictates](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0):

> script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are
>   inserted.

I'm making assumptions here, but it's probably to introduce a layer of security so that you don't accidentally introduce XSS or [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#HTML_script_injection).

---

If you want to get the scripts to run, take their content, create a specific `<script>` element, set the script's body to the content, and then insert that into the DOM:

```js
const script = document.createElement("script"),
  text = document.createTextNode("console.log('foo')");

script.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(script);
```