# Angular, DomSanitizer, bypassSecurity script

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm playing with `bypassSecurityTrust*` functions of Angular. Goal is to get a `script` tag to execute on the page. But it either keeps sanitizing with the message

`WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content`

or I see in the console a

`SafeHtmlImpl {changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity: "<script>alert(1)</script>`.

Goal is to get this working.

What I currently use and tried:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value: string): string {
    console.log(this.sanitized.sanitize(SecurityContext.NONE, value))
    return this.sanitized.sanitize(SecurityContext.NONE, value);
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.css']
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string;
  html: string;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.html = "<script> alert(8) </script>";
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

and the template html:

```
<div [innerHtml]="html | safeHtml"></div>
```

I tried both `sanitize` with `SecurityContext.NONE` which should work looking at the [code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.ts#L155) and `bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value)`. The above code was inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39858064/857990).

Any ideas on how to execute that JavaScript?

Comment: I don't think the sanitizer is the thing that is stopping this from working.  It's the regular HTML spec that says `<scripts>`s added in innerHTML won't be executed.  See :[Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1197575/691711) and my answer to this question: [Why doesn't a browser run a <script> in an HTML fragment retrieved via fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49867302/691711).

Comment: So how could I put the string on the page?

Comment: `<div id="attack8">
  {{ html | safeHtml }}
</div>` doesn't work either. Again the changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So yes, innerHtml can't insert script tags, but it doesn't stop it from one of the many other ways to inject JavaScript.

Working example:

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext} from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value: string) {
    console.log(this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value));
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  template: `
    <div [innerHtml]="html | safeHtml">
    </div>
  `
})

export class DemoComponent {

  html: string;
  h_html: string;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.html = "<svg onload=\"alert(1)\"> blah </svg>"
    this.h_html = sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, "<svg onload=\"alert(2)\"> blah </svg>');
  }
}
```

What doesn't work is

```
return this.sanitized.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, value);
```

or using

```
<div [innerHtml]="h_tmpl"></div>
```

Not sure why. Should behave the same afaiu.